# Python Inheritance Output

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7, inheritance

```
class ParentClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 1
        self.y = 10
    def PRINT(self):
        print (self.__x, self.y)

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__()
        self.__x = 2
        self.y = 20


c = ChildClass()
c.PRINT()
```

Why is the output (1, 20)? I know how I got 20, but shouldn't it be 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expand slightly on poke's answer...

From [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references)

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores,
>   at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with
>   _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard
>   to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs
>   within the definition of a class.

So if we add this line to the end of your code:

```
print c._ChildClass__x, c._ParentClass__x,
```

it will print

```
(1, 20)
2 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Members that start with two underscores are “private”. Although Python does not have a real way to restrict access to members, it does some name mangling to give them a more complicated name so they stay more or less private.

So in your case, `ParentClass` has a `__x` field that is used in the `PRINT` method. And `ChildClass` has a separate, independent `__x` field that is not used anywhere. So for the printing, only the parent’s `__x` is used.

To fix this, simply change the two underscores to a single underscore, to mark the name as “internal” but not private to the type.

Comment: What he said. Also, you can still access the private object by accounting for the name mangling and accessing `ParentClass()._ParentClass__x`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don’t access name-wrangled members. That’s defeating the point.

Comment: Isn't it called name *mangling*, not name *wrangling*? I'm pretty sure wrangle means to round up livestock or to argue, and mangle means to mess something up so it is unidentifiable. Although I do like the mental image of rounding up variable names...

Comment: Yes, @poke agreed that's not necessarily recommended!

Comment: @SethMMorton Now that you mention it, you’re right. I wonder how often I made this mistake by now… >_<

Comment: @SethMMorton: While humming the theme from _Rawhide_. :)

Answer (score 0):

For 'private' variable (`__` as prefix) in a class, name of it has been changed. You can use the new name to call variable accordingly. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class ParentClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 1
        self.y = 10
    def PRINT(self):
        print (self.__x, self.y)
        print (self._ParentClass__x, self.y)
        print (self._ChildClass__x, self.y)

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ChildClass, self).__init__()
        self.__x = 2
        self.y = 20


c = ChildClass()
c.PRINT()
```

OUTPUT:

```
(1, 20)
(1, 20)
(2, 20)
```

Comment: I realise that your code is just to illustrate a language point, but the 3rd line in your `.PRINT()` method is a little scary. If we do e.g., `p = ParentClass(); p.PRINT()` we get `AttributeError: 'ParentClass' object has no attribute '_ChildClass__x'`

Comment: @PM2Ring I think in this case, PRINT() won't be invoked in this way since this is just an example but not a program.